# Getting API of a third party Outlook COM AddIn

Tags: vba, outlook, com, outlook-addin

I have a third party COM AddIn that modifies my emails before sending. I would like to interact with it in VBA but do not know the API. Since recording does not appear to be an option [1](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-record-macros-in-outlook) I am at a loss as to how to identify my options.
How can I learn which methods/objects exist?

Comment: If you have a reference to it then it should be visible in the object browser (View.Object Browser or F2)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to interact with third-party COM add-ins until developers disclose their public methods and properties. You may contact add-in developers to get access to their API (if any).

But I'd recommend creating a VBA macro without touching any third-party add-ins. You can handle the `ItemSend` event of the `Application` class as well. It is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an `Inspector` (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the `Send` button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem`, is used in a program.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
 
 Dim prompt As String 
 
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
 
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
 
 Cancel = True 
 
 End If 
 
End Sub
```